# Altering 2 columns in table - risky operation?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, alter-table

I have a table with ~100 columns, about ~30M rows, on MSSQL server 2005.

I need to alter 2 columns - change their types from VARCHAR(1024) to VARCHAR(max).  These columns does not have index on them.

I'm worried that doing so will fill up the log, and cause the operation to fail.  How can I estimate the needed free disk space, both of the data and the log, needed for such operation to ensure it will not fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, increasing the column size (including to MAX) will generate a huge log for a large table, because every row will be updated (behind the scenens the old column gets dropped and a new column gets added and data is copied).

1. Add a new column of type `VARCHAR(MAX) NULL`. As a nullable column, will be added as metadata only (no data update)
2. Copy the data from the old column to new column. This can be done in batches to alleviate the log pressure.
3. Drop the old column. This will be a metadata only operation.
4. Use [`sp_rename`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx) to rename the new column to the old column name.
5. Later, at your convenience, rebuild the clustered index (online if needed) to get rid of the space occupied by the old column

This way you get control over the log by controlling the batches at step 2). You also minimize the disruption on permissions, constraints and relations by not copying the entire table into a new one (as SSMS so poorly does...).

You can do this sequence for both columns at once.

Comment: Sound the best solution for my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you consider, instead:

1. Create a new table with the new schema
2. Copy data from old table to new table
3. Drop old table
4. Rename new table to name of old table

This might be a far less costly operation and could possibly be done with minimal logging using INSERT/SELECT (if this were SQL Server 2008 or higher).

Answer (score 1):

Why would increasing the VARCHAR limit fill up the log?

Comment: I suppose you can perform this op on a smaller table and check the actual cost after the op is complete to know for certain...

Answer (score 0):

Try to do some test in smaller pieces. I mean, you could create the same structure locally with few thousand rows, and see the difference before and after. I think the change will be linear. The real question is about redo log, if it will fit into it or not, since you can do it at once. Must you do it online, or you can stop production for a while? If you can stop, maybe there is a way to stop redo log in MSSQL like in Oracle. It could make it a lot faster. If you need to do it online, you could try to make a new column, copy the value into it by a cycle for example 100000 rows at once, commit, continue. After completing maybe to drop original column and rename new one is faster than altering.